# Why did Windows remove the ScanDisk GUI?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, gui, scan-disk

Why isn't the ScanDisk graphical user interface available on Windows XP and Windows Vista (maybe Windows 7 also)?

Comment: what GUI are you referring to?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because it is no longer known as ScanDisk?

Windows 98 **ScanDisk** GUI

[image]

Windows XP **Check Disk** GUI

[image]

Comment: For the record: Afaik it was never called Scandisk on Windows (NT), only on WinDOS.

Answer (score 2):

You can right click the partition you want to scan, select properties, select tools, and click on "check now" button. That'll check your disk for errors.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 7 will have a UI returning, but not graphical.

From the [Engineering Windows 7 Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/01/25/disk-defragmentation-background-and-engineering-the-windows-7-improvements.aspx):

> In Windows Vista, we had removed all
>   of the UI that would provide detailed
>   defragmentation status. We received
>   feedback that you didn’t like this
>   decision, so we listened, evaluated
>   the various tradeoffs, and have built
>   a new GUI for defrag! As a result, in
>   Windows 7, you can monitor status more
>   easily and intuitively. Further,
>   defragmentation can be safely
>   terminated any time during the process
>   and on all volumes very simply (if
>   required).

Comment: That's nice to know, but this question is about scandisk, not defrag.

Comment: It'd be nice if combined scan disk and defrag together as one.